# Is it possible to access resources inside a jar through their path?

Tags: java, jar, soapui, embedded-resource

I have a SoapUI project running through a java project that is all packaged into a jar. The project runs fine unpackaged through my IDE, but it encounters problems when running the jar through the command line. Here is the code that is causing the problem:

```
SoapUITestCaseRunner runner = new SoapUITestCaseRunner();
ClassLoader cl = MyClass.class.getClassLoader();
runner.setProjectFile(cl.getResource("project.xml").getFile());
runner.run();
```

The problem occurs on the run method when it tries to read in the xml file from the jar. Is it possible for me to get a path that I can input to the [setProjectFile](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/tools/AbstractSoapUIRunner.html#setProjectFile(java.lang.String)) method from the jar? I've seen other answers say to use a stream, but this method only accepts strings.

Here is the stack trace:

> 2014-07-23 12:03:58,384 ERROR [errorlog] com.eviware.soapui.support.SoapUIException: Failed to load project from file [file:/C:/temp/MyJar.jar!/project.xml]
>   com.eviware.soapui.support.SoapUIException: Failed to load project from file [file:/C:/temp/MyJar.jar!/project.xml]
>     at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject.loadProject(WsdlProject.java:315)
>     at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject.(WsdlProject.java:231)
>     at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProjectFactory.createNew(WsdlProjectFactory.java:41)
>     at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProjectFactory.createNew(WsdlProjectFactory.java:28)
>     at com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner.runRunner(SoapUITestCaseRunner.java:329)
>     at com.eviware.soapui.tools.AbstractSoapUIRunner.run(AbstractSoapUIRunner.java:188)
>     at CommercialTests.ComTest.doTest(ComTest.java:14)
>     at CommercialTests.ServiceTests.main(ServiceTests.java:8)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\temp\MyJar.jar!\project.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
>     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>     at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>     at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
>     at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.UrlWsdlLoader.handleFile(UrlWsdlLoader.java:180)
>     at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.UrlWsdlLoader.load(UrlWsdlLoader.java:116)
>     at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.UrlWsdlLoader.load(UrlWsdlLoader.java:96)
>     at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject.loadProject(WsdlProject.java:297)
>     ... 7 more

Comment: It looks like it's expecting a local file (that jarUrl should have worked, otherwise)... you may have to copy the file out of the jar first (maybe into a tempFile), and then point to that.

Comment: How would you suggest I go about that?

Comment: instead of passing the URL directly to `runner.setProjectFile`, create a new tempFile, and write the contents out to disk, then pass the pathh to the tempfile to `runner.setProjectFile`

Comment: It doesn't seem to like that option either. I tried copying the file to a temp file outside the jar, and it can't handle any kind of path inside the jar.

Answer (score 1):

For something like this I normally do:

```
URL res = getClass().getResource("/project.xml")    // is it at the root of your jar?!?!
File f = new File(res.getFile())
runner.setProjectFile(f.getCanonicalPath());
```

SoapUI, depending on how it accesses the file, might need it in the "real" world. Below is a much more resource-intensive version of the above.

```
// locate your file in the jar resources
URL res = getClass().getResource("/project.xml")    // is it at the root of your jar?!?!
// locate the resource in the filesystem
File f = new File(res.getFile())
// copy the file out into the real filesystem
File target = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + File.separator + f.getName())
java.nio.file.Files.copy(f.toPath(), target.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
runner.setProjectFile(target.getCanonicalPath())
```

Comment: The problem is that the "setProjectFile" method only accepts strings, so it won't accept "f" as a parameter.

Comment: I tried with f.getPath and f.getAbsolutePath, and both of those are giving me the same error.

Comment: Try the second option.